# Hardware for removeable fencing section?

Tags: fence, hardware, backyard

I have a fence around my backyard. On the one side is a standard gate. The other side currently has no access. I have a section that I secured just with a few screws so that I could easily unscrew it in order to let something through like a small skid steer or bobcat. I'd like to update that section with hardware that makes it easier to unpin and lift out, but I don't know what the hardware I'm looking for would be called.

Ideally, the crossbars of the section would lift off of some pins mounted to the posts (for reference, it is [this fence panel](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-5-ft-x-8-ft-Space-Picket-French-Gothic-Scallop-Wood-Fence-Panel-73000129/304125612) from Home Depot) and possibly have enough height on the pin to go through the crossbar and peak out the top so that I can put a pin through just to keep the kids from lifting it off.

any help is appreciated

Comment: What are you actually asking? Does such a thing exist? What could you use to jerry-rig something like this? Is a pull-pin somehow better than just unscrewing a fence section (which is what I've done over the years)? Please [edit] to ask a question, then take the [tour] to see how we're a bit different here than your standard discussion forum.

Comment: Without seeing the posts and how your rails interface to them, your solution space may be empty. My first thought is 4 sliding bolt locks. My second thought is 1'-0" of 3/4" diameter aluminum pipe and 2'-0" of 5/8" aluminum rod. Aluminum is easy to machine. You can drill a large hole in one sidewall of pipe to provide access for fastening the opposite sidewall directly to wood surfaces. You can easily drill 5/8" aluminum rod. The aluminum I spec'ed above is 9 USD at my local metal shop.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong with big hinges and suitable locks or pins / latches.

Comment: Hey Solar, this is another of your answers that has been (automatically?) flagged as low quality because of length. You may want to consider adding a bit of filler to the meat to keep the system happy. Also, this was exactly my first thought, so +1.

Answer (score 2):

There may not be any designed-for-purpose hardware, however, you can develop a solution with some creativity.

Those horizontal rails aren't quite 2x4 size -- but are they close? If so then maybe you could mount a set of "sockets" like the Simpson fence bracket to the posts and then lift the fence panel in and out of those. (photo: strongtie.com)

[image: Simpson Strong-Tie FB]

Or, maybe a "bat wing hinge" could be mounted to both ends of both rails so that the fence panel can be lifted in/out similarly. This is something you can buy ready-made, but you also could fabricate your own with skills, tools, and materials you already have. (photo: [www.tsdistributors.com](http://www.tsdistributors.com)) Be creative: the pin part could mount to the stationary post pointing upward, or could mount to the movable panel pointing downward.

[image: bat wing hinge]

The mounting hardware may not easily deter kids lifting the panel, but you can add an extra feature that interferes with removal of the panel. A lag screw driven partly into the post above the panel rail could interfere with panel removal.

If you build your own version of a bat wing hinge you could build it with bolts or threaded rod rather than smooth; this would provide a spot where a retainer nut could be spun on. Make it a nylon lock nut so it can't be turned by fingers alone, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, this is a problem rural areas have been solving for a long time. You can borrow or adapt their solution.

The reasons not to use a single gate (need to move wide equipment through) don't apply to double gates - large double gates can easily accommodate two lanes. Gates can be made to look very similar to an existing wood, metal or vinyl fence, if aesthetics are a consideration. That does leave the stability of the gates, especially at the midpoint - but there's a solution for that, too. A piece of hardware called a "Drop Rod" (or Drop Pin or Drop Bolt) attaches to the gate and pushes a few inches into the ground to help stabilize the midpoint where the gates meet so children, animals or wind pushing on it doesn't swing them open. You lift the rods to open the gate (and usually open a latch of some sort as well).

[image: drop rod]

(image is from Home Depot but no endorsement is intended or implied)

Alternatively, if you're really looking for a unique solution, you could make use of these "drop rods" to firmly attach your temporary fence sections - but I'd argue that making a large gate is a better solution and well worth the effort.